# Group theory finding proper subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

The smallest order for a group to have a non-abelian proper subgroup? I am confused how shall I proceed pls help
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the size of the smallest nonabelian group?  From this information, what do you expect to be the smallest size of a group with a nonabelian proper subgroup?

Answer (score 3):

A finite group of order $p$ or $p^2$ for some prime $p$ is abelian. Then the proper subgroups of groups of order $1$ up to $11$ are always abelian. For $12$, we have $S_3\times C_2$ which has a non-abelian subgroup ($S_3$).

Answer (score 0):

the smallest non abelian group is $S_3$ symetric group on three objet, so a group that have a smallest order and have  aproper non-abelian subgroup is group product $S_3\times\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z} $,

Comment: This reasoning is incomplete. It doesn't immediately follow that the smallest group with a nonabelian proper subgroup contains the smallest nonabelian group as a proper subgroup (it happens to be true, but it requires more justification).

Comment: Good,  the smallest positive  number  different  of one 
is 2 then the smallest order of the group wanted is 12.

Answer (score -1):

So it's a long method but I son't see how else we can find a MINIMUM.

We'd consider all orders from 1 to the minimum(Which shall be 12, one by one)

1 - Trivially Abelian

2 - Abelian

3 - Abelian

4 - Cyclic or isomorphic to Z(2) + Z(2), so Abelian

5 - Cyclic

6 - Is of order 2*3 where 3 is prime so isomorphic to D(3) or Z(2p). In either case all its proper subgroups are Abelian. Or you could use the fact that by Lagrange's theorem, all its proper subgroups are of order 2 or 3 and are hence Abelian

7- Cyclic

8 - By Lagrange's theorem, all its proper subgroups are of order 1,2 or 4

9 - By Lagrange's theorem, all its proper subgroups are of order 3

10 - By Lagrange's theorem, all its proper subgroups are of order 2 or 5 and are hence Cyclic and Abelian

11 - Cyclic

12 - Simply consider D(3)+ Z(2), where '+' denotes the external direct product sign and take its subgroup D(3) + {0}. It shall be a non-Abelian group of order 6.

I know this is an unorganised way of writing, I have also left some blank spaces since I found them to be 'obvious' results. If something is incorrect or vague, have me know and I'd rectify it.